# Dual booting Dell Inspiron 14

Tags: boot, dual-boot, dell

I bought a new Dell Inspiron 14 which has Intel I7 processor.

I tried installing Ubuntu as 2nd OS by following this [link](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-windows-8-or-10-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en#BIOS).

I followed all the steps such as partitioning the C drive and setting up the Boot configurations.

I do get the Ubuntu install screen. It proceeds normally till the screen after Wifi selection screen. On this screen it always says that "You need 8.6 GB space to install software and other updates, but you have only 8 GB available."

It never lets me select the space I freed up from C drive of the Windows.

Has anyone else faced this problem?

I checked other questions here, but they seem old and not relevant to my problem.

Thank you!

**EDIT** (image added):
[screen after wifi selection screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RvMb.jpg)

Comment: Hi, "the screen after Wifi selection screen" has an option called "Something else" down the bottom. You may need to use it to set up partitions manually, or even only view how Ubuntu detects the layout.

Comment: @mikewhatever : NO, there is no such option on this screen! After the wifi screen, i see a screen with title "Updates and other software" with only three buttons - quit, back and continue ... Please see the image in the edited post above!